# How to get a gene string from DNA

Tags: python-3.x

Biologists use a sequence of letters A, C, T, and G to model a genome. A gene is a substrsing of a genome that starts after a triplet ATG and ends before a triplet TAG, TAA, or TGA. Furthermore, the length of a gene string is a multiple of 3 and the gene does not contain any of the triplets ATG, TAG, TAA, and TGA.

```
sequence =    ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC
CCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGC
CTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGG
AAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCC
CTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAG
TTTAATTACAGACCTGAA
```

my code: 
I'm just a beginner in python

```
 seq = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"

sequence = ""

for i in range(len(seq)-1):
    triplet = 'ATG'
    if i == triplet:
       i += 1
       while True:
            i += 1
            if i == ['TAG','TAA', 'TGA']:
            sequence.append(i)
            break

print(sequence)
```

The program must print the gene strings in the sequence

help me out please

Comment: Please include a description of what you think the program should be doing. Ie state the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: have you investigated the problems in your code? which part is failing? what output are you getting and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Not relevant to the coding, but ATG can occur in a sequence. It codes for Methionine as well as a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems I can see.

```
for i in range(len(seq)-1):
    triplet = 'ATG'
    if i == triplet:
```

The variable `i` is an integer. `triplet` is a string (why are you assigning triplet inside the loop?)  So i==triplet is always false. Most of the body of the loop is never executed.

```
 i += 1
```

Since i is your loop variable, why are you incrementing it?

```
        if i == ['TAG','TAA', 'TGA']:
        sequence.append(i)
```

Again, the comparison between an integer and a list is always false. The next line isn't indented (a syntax error), and you can't append to strings. So `sequence` should probably be a list, not a string.

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a code writing service.  I would use seq.find to find the index of the  first ATG codon, split the remainder of the string in a comprehension,  find the stop codon, and then join the remaining parts together.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp solution:

```
seq = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"

import re

for m in (re.findall('(ATG(...)+?(TAG|TAA|TGA))', seq)):
  print('gene {}'.format(m[0]))
```

Output. Please specify expected output if different:

```
gene ATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGT
GGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTG
GTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAG
GCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAA
TAA
gene ATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAA
```